# Trying to target a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

Im trying to create some conditional logic depending on the status the users membership.

Below shows the array for my 'status':

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$args = array( 
    'status' => array( 'wcm-active', 'wcm-delayed', 'wcm-complimentary', 'wcm-pending', 'wcm-paused', 'wcm-expired', 'wcm-cancelled' ),
);  
$active_memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_id, $args );
```

I then want to write a conditional statement then to target specific statuses. For example if i wanted to target just 'wcm-delayed'. Below is what i have but doesnt seem to work:

```
if ($active_memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_id, $args[0][1] )) {
   show content
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way of doing this just by simplifying the array so it only includes one status at a time. Not ideal, but allows me to target a specific user status like i was trying to do.

See code below:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
$args = array( 'status' => 'wcm-active' );  
$active_memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_id, $args ); 

if ($active_memberships == wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_id, $args['status']['wcm-active'] )) { 
echo 'This content only shows for active statuses'; 
}
```